# how can i print text files without \n in python

Tags: python, text-files, txt

```
open("usernames.txt", "r")
open("passwords.txt", "r")

with open("usernames.txt", "r") as users:
    usernames = users.readlines()

with open("passwords.txt", "r") as user_passwords:
    passwords = user_passwords.readlines()

print(usernames)
print(passwords)
```

i currently have this for my code, but it outputs it like this `tenn\n` i need to have it like this `tenn`

Comment: this is because you write each username in different line

Comment: you can use "Rejex" for this case, or make a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read like this:

```py
with open("passwords.txt", "r") as user_passwords:
    passwords = user_passwords.read().splitlines()
```

This reads the entire file first and then splits them by lines.

Comment: Please accept the answer since it worked for you. Thanks!

Comment: i am new to this how do you accept a answer?

Comment: Just click on tick mark below the upvote/downvote to the left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can also replace the \n with nothing

```
with open("passwords.txt", "r") as user_passwords:
    passwords = user_passwords.read().replace('\n', '')
```

Comment: This is wrong, because `passwords` would be a single string without any '\n' in your case. OP's `passwords` variable is a list with each element having '\n' at the end.